# What are my options for self-hosting SignalR?

Tags: c#, signalr, nancy

I want to add SignalR to my Windows service, written in C#, targetting .NET 4.0. The `Microsoft.Owin.*` packages appear to require .NET 4.5.

I'd also like to include NancyFX in the same process, for other reasons.

What's the best way to self-host SignalR?

Comment: I'm sure you have good reasons to not want to go to .NET 4.5 - but without an appropriate disclaimer you're going to get answers that suggest just that :)

Comment: Going to .NET 4.5 is definitely an option, but I'd like to explorer non-OWIN (and non-ASP.NET) hosting options first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the signalR package (v. 1.1.2) using .net 4.0. Work as a charm. I cannot use 4.5 as I am still at VS2010.

I use it with a standard web project with a WebService handling the communication.

Comment: Ah. SignalR 2.0 requires .NET 4.5, but 1.1 works with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

The only Microsoft OWIN package that requires 4.5 is owinhost.exe (used to be katana.exe), you can still use normal http listener (Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener) to self host just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the packages as listed at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host they should work just fine under .NET 4.0. It's worth remembering that you can always use the package manager console to explicitly install older versions of packages if you need to - although for SignalR at the time of writing there is no need to do this.